# How to create / get the API key for the Geonames

Tags: react-native, geonames

I have tried to find anything about how to get the API key from Geonames, I have search here on Stackoverflow, on Youtube and even on Geonames own website but I can´t find anything about how to get the API key.

Please need some help!